# Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault Aborted

Tags: python, pygame, kivy

I am atemping to make a grocery list program in python using the kivy GUI and a button is hit I want it to add a custom floatlayout to a boxlayout. The floatlayout has a check box and a label. I keep getting this error Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
Aborted when ever i run it though here is my .py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class All(BoxLayout):

  def addIngredient(self):
    ing = Ingredient(name = self.ids.textInput.text)

    self.ids.list.add_widget(ListItem(ing))
    self.ids.button.text = 'done'

class ListItem(FloatLayout):

  def __init__(self, ing):
    self.ing = ing

class Ingredient():

  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

class ListApp(App):
  def build(self):
    return All()

if __name__ == "__main__":

  ListApp().run()
```

Here is my .kv file:

```
<All>:
  orientation: 'vertical'
  BoxLayout: 
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    TextInput:
      id: textInput
    Button:
      text: 'Add'
      on_press: root.addIngredient()
      id: button
  BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    id: list

<ListItem>:
  CheckBox:
    size_hint: 0.2, 1
  Label:
    size_hint: 0.35, 1
    text: ing.name
    halign: 'left'
   valign: 'middle'
```

The error always occurs at this line:

```
self.ids.list.add_widget(ListItem(ing))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class ListItem(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, ing):
        self.ing = ing
```

My guess is that your problem arises from overriding the `__init__` of the ListItem, but not calling the superclass `__init__`; this is where the widget internals would normally be set up, so you end up with an improperly-instantiated widget that causes problems when you try to add it to something.

To fix it, use the normal python method to call the superclass method:

```
class ListItem(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, ing):
        super(ListItem, self).__init__()
        self.ing = ing
```

It's unfortunate that it makes pygame just segfault. Maybe with the SDL2 backend you would get a more helpul error. You should try to use kivy 1.9 with SDL2 anyway.

Comment: Ok so I'm super new in Python and kivy so can you explain super class init SLD2 and how to get kivy 1.9? Thanks you are awesome

Comment: Download kivy using the instructions on its website. And for the class stuff, google it, this is normal stuff for interacting with python's object structure.